# Unexplainable file deletion on dev machine (macOS X)

Tags: laravel, macos, phpstorm

I am having this weird problem, in a certain Laravel project where some files are just deleted or renamed weirdly. I am the only user on the machine, I have other projects too but I haven't seen anything like this happen to any of these other projects.

I've also noticed that the files being deleted or renamed are the same, I have been using git to control revert back to the stable state but now this is becoming nuisance and thus have decided to seek help around here. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What files are deleted/renamed weirdly? Are they core Laravel files or some you've created yourself? Would be good to post their path relative to Laravel project.

Comment: @user8555937 these are files I've created myself, I am of course not using git to track laravel files, (composer instead)

Comment: My suspicion is you have made an unwanted/corrupted commit on GIT and each time you're doing checkout or something like that, the files are rewritten based on unwanted commit. I'd create another git repository with the files which are in good shape and not bother with corrupted repo anymore.

Comment: Sure, there are ways to verify for bad commits and rollback the HEAD manually but I don't know them.

Comment: PhpStorm has Local History functionality (sort of built-in simple VCS, it always works regardless if you use proper VCS or not). See what it has to say about it -- it may give some clues. It should also allow you to restore (some of the) deleted files (it depends, of course). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/local-history.html

Comment: @LazyOne recovery is not really an issue, because I am using git to do the management for me, the issue is having to do this every now and then. Its becoming nuisance